# Failed to connect with gRPC to remote LND: failed to connect to all addresses unavailable

Tags: bitcoind, lightning-network-daemon, grpc

I want to connect to my LND running on a raspberry pi linux from my macOS with gRPC. On the raspberry pi is also a bitcoin full node running bitcoind regtest. I used this tutorial: https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/docs/grpc/python.md
There is a good chance I do something obvious wrong.

lnd.conf on linux:

```
[Application Options]
#this is the public ip of the raspberry pi
tlsextraip=87.228.187.58 

[Bitcoin]
bitcoin.active=true
bitcoin.regtest=true
bitcoin.node=bitcoind

[Bitcoind]
bitcoind.rpchost=localhost
bitcoind.rpcuser=aUser
bitcoind.rpcpass=aPass
bitcoind.zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
bitcoind.zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28333
```

I deleted the tls.cert and tls.key and restarted lnd.

bitcoin.conf on linux:

```
rpcauth=...

zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28333

txindex=1
regtest=1
daemon=1
```

Works perfectly.

On macOS i followed the steps in the tutorial.
Created the virtualenv, installed dependencies, cloned the repo, copied the proto file and compiled it.

I created client.py file with this content:

```
import lightning_pb2 as ln
import lightning_pb2_grpc as lnrpc
import grpc
import os

os.environ["GRPC_SSL_CIPHER_SUITES"] = 'HIGH+ECDSA'

cert = open(os.path.expanduser('~/Library/Application Support/Lnd/tls.cert'), 'rb').read()
creds = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(cert)
channel = grpc.secure_channel('87.228.187.58:10009', creds)
stub = lnrpc.LightningStub(channel)

response = stub.WalletBalance(ln.WalletBalanceRequest())
print(response.total_balance)
```

When I execute the client.py, first it said it can not find the file tls.cert because this file is (in my understanding) supposed to be on the linux system. Anyway I installed the LND also on macOS with the same lnd.conf file and run it.

When I execute the client.py now, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/Documents/projects/lnd/client.py", line 18, in <module>
    response = stub.WalletBalance(ln.WalletBalanceRequest())
  File "~/Documents/projects/lnd/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 1030, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "~/Documents/projects/lnd/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 910, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)  # pytype: disable=not-instantiable
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
        details = "failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNAVAILABLE: ipv4:87.228.187.58:10009: Failed to connect to remote host: FD shutdown"
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNAVAILABLE: ipv4:87.228.187.58:10009: Failed to connect to remote host: FD shutdown {grpc_status:14, created_time:"2023-04-22T17:06:33.920693+03:00"}"
```

Bitcoind and LND is running on Linux. LND says:

```
RPC server listening on 127.0.0.1:10009
```

I got the tlsextraip from a website saying this is my public ip address.

I tried setting rpclisten=87.228.187.58:10009 and rpclisten=0.0.0.0:10009 on linux but does not work. Same error.

Am I doing something obvious wrong, or until now is the main part correct?
How can I fix the problem?

Thanks in advance